# How to handle constantly changing properties in data held by redux stores?

Tags: javascript, properties, reactjs, redux, derived

I have about 5000 items that I need to render as a table. I'm using redux to hold them and these items have duration property, as time progresses the duration property should be updated.

As a first cut I'm pushing from server with duration every 5 seconds and that's no big problem as table is paginated so not all those items are rendered to DOM. I don't have a problem with performance however I'm introducing more features that requires me to stop doing that and also it is a waste as even when the core data doesn't change I'm still pushing it because the duration has changed.

I should be pushing items to client only when new items are added or when items are removed. But somehow I need to update duration on the client side. I could think of few ways to do it, like have a timer service that runs in background and sends an action to redux store to update duration on all the items. But not sure if it's a good approach, could anyone please advise?

Comment: Could you describe how do you calculate duration? Is it just difference of some field, like `created_at` and current time? If so, you don't need to update your state, because you can just calculate it in `render()`

Comment: @AlexandrSubbotin I haven't got the code to calculate duration on client yet, but yea the plan is to derive that data. However if I just do that in `render()` then what will trigger the `render()` every 10 secs to update duration? I'd still have to dispatch some action to redux store to start rendering again isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the background service dispatching an action periodically is the obvious way to do it. You could have the service enable/disable itself by listening to changes to the Redux state, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As I described in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781008/how-to-handle-constantly-changing-properties-in-data-held-by-redux-stores?noredirect=1#comment59251182_35781008), you can calculate duration in your `render()` method of component. I.e. your current code is:

```
    render() {
       return this.props.items.map(item => <Duration duration={item.duration}>)
    }
```

And you calculate duration like `new Date().getTime() - item.created_at`. So, you can calculate duration in `render()` and forceUpdate component every 10 seconds:

```
   componentDidMount() {
     setInterval(this.forceUpdate.bind(this), 10000); //re-render component every 10 seconds
   }
   render() {
     const now = new Date().getTime();
     return this.props.items.map(item => <Duration duration={now - item.created_at}>)
   }
```